# Separate value in array more than one (implode)

Tags: php, arrays, implode

Let say i have a string:

```
"fruit: apple, fruit: orange, vegetable: carrot,"
```

i would like to to store it like this:

```
type[] => fruit,vegetable

item[] => apple,orange,carrot
```

can anyone help me on this?

Comment: explode on coma, loop, explode on colon. your desired output seems a little odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a code that will parse your string into 2 arrays.

```
<?php
$type=array();
$item=array();
$a="fruit: apple, fruit: orange, vegetable: carrot,";
foreach (explode(',',trim($a,',')) as $csv){
    list($k,$v)=explode(':',$csv);
    $k=trim($k);
    $v=trim($v);
    if($k && $v){
        if(!in_array($k,$type)) $type[]=$k;
        if(!in_array($v,$item)) $item[]=$v;
    }
}
print_r($type);
print_r($item);
```

if you want the $type to be a CSV single string like in your question, you can use join like this:

```
print join(',',$type);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

This code will put it in an `array` so you can easily acces it, [**see DEMO**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/77ddfcb33d708d780cd73605dea9a9c23f0dae29)

```
<?php
$string = "fruit: apple,fruit: orange,vegetable: carrot";
$output = array(array());
foreach(explode(",", $string) as $item){
    $parts = explode(": ",trim($item));
    if(array_key_exists($parts[0], $output)){
        array_push($output[$parts[0]], $parts[1]);
    }else{
        $output[$parts[0]] = array($parts[1]);
    }
}
?>
```

It will give you an `array` like this as a result

```
<?php
$output = array(
    "fruit" => array(
        "apple",
        "orange"
        ),
    "vegetable" => array(
        "carrot"
        )
    );
?>
```

To then later gain that information, you do like this:

```
$output["fruit"][0];
```

This will give you a result of: *apple* in this case.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer. but i agree with the query

Comment: Yes, I see now. I've not actually paid attention to the first part of his question. I'll edit this answer.

Comment: you haven't converted the string. its easy when you start with an array ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$string = "fruit: apple, fruit: orange, vegetable: carrot,";
preg_match_all("/([a-zA-Z0-9]*): ([a-zA-Z0-9]*),/U", $string, $output_array);
print_r($output_array);
```

Should return something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => fruit: apple,
            [1] => fruit: orange,
            [2] => vegetable: carrot,
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => fruit
            [1] => fruit
            [2] => vegetable
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => orange
            [2] => carrot
        )

)
```